# 403 CSRF token error using Vaadin with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to implement spring security in vaadin application, but I have a problem, after logging to page, it shows me an error:

> {"status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Could not verify the
>   provided CSRF token because your session was not found.","path":"/"}

I was trying many things but none of them works, here is my standard security config class:

```
//SecurityConfig.java    
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user")
            .password("password")
            .roles("USER");
    }
}
```

Controller class:

```
//HomeController.java
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Welcome to the home page!";
    }

@GetMapping("/error")
public String error(){
    return "Error!";
}
```

}

And Vaadin UI class

```
//VaadinUI.java
@SpringUI
public class VaadinUI extends UI {
    VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();

    com.vaadin.ui.Label label = new com.vaadin.ui.Label("Witaj");

    @Autowired
    public VaadinUI() {}

   @Override
   protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
       setContent(layout);
       layout.addComponent(label);
   }
```

}

And my pom.xml

```
//pom.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>example.com</groupId>
        <artifactId>LDAPSpringInitializr</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>

        <name>LDAPSpringInitializr</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>

        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <vaadin.version>8.0.5</vaadin.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-ldap</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                    <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>


    </project>
```

How to use Vaadin with spring security?
I want to connect spring security with LDAP later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with Vaadin, but this post https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/filter-based-spring-security-in-vaadin-applications suggests that Vaadin already provides CSRF protection, so you can disable it in Spring via

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.csrf().disable();
}
```

in your SecurityConfig.

Comment: Vaadin with Spring security works ! I'm trying now to connect with LDAP, greetings !